# Changing the default SharePoint Online site for direct access

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, homepage

When users click on SharePoint Online, I'd like them to go directly to the homepage of our main site, rather than needing to go through Microsofts layout page.

I.e. rather than this: https://company.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx
[image]

I'd like them to go directly into this: https://company.sharepoint.com/SitePages/One-Vision.aspx

[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: This is not possible, if I understand it correctly. you want to change 'SharePoint' Home button on the suite bar (also called Hub page) rather than a page on the site.

Comment: Yes, the page that a user goes to when they initially click on the "SharePoint" icon within Office 365 is currently the generic Microsoft page. We do not want to use this page, but instead progress directly to the root site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at this stage.  We cannot customize the SharePoint Home/Hub page ('SharePoint' button the Office 365 Suite Bar).  There is a uservoice created already please feel free to vote and let Microsoft know how important it is important.

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/14844912-add-customization-possibility-to-the-new-sharepoin

Comment: Thanks SharePointer. Good to know that I shouldn't spend time trying to achieve this! Will vote for the change in uservoice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change the home page of your sharepoint root site. follow the instruction mentioned here "[Use a different page for your SharePoint site home page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-different-page-for-your-SharePoint-site-home-page-35a5022c-f84a-455d-985e-c691ab5dfa17)"

- Go to the Pages library of your site. To do this:
- On your site, click Pages in the left navigation. Or, if you don't
  see Pages, go to Settings  Gear shaped settings button at the top
  right, and then Site Contents. On the Site contents page, select Site
  pages.
- From within the library, find the page you want to make a homepage,
  and then select it by clicking the circular option button to the left
  of the page title.
- Click the vertical ellipses (...) next to the page title, and then
  click Make homepage.

[image]

**EDIT**

This is not possible as of now, Microsoft wont allow to change the landing page of SharePoint.aspx. As a workaround (ugly), you can create a new tile and promote it on top, let user use that one. Please see this article for more information:
[Add custom tiles to the app launcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/manage/customize-the-app-launcher?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: I've already changed the home page of our sharepoint root site, however, it does not progress directly to this page when a user clicks on the "SharePoint" icon within Office 365, instead it progresses to the layouts page I included above, meaning the user has an additional step to get onto our SharePoint homepage.


We do not need a navigation page as our site is not large, so it is an unnecessary additional step.

Comment: you want to change the SharePoint home page when user click on the SharePoint icon in the Suit navigation or app launcher? right?

Comment: Yeah that's the one!

Comment: that is not possible as of now. One cannot change the functionality of SharePoint home button in app launcher. a workaround of it, you can crate a custom tile for your users.

Comment: Thanks Waqas - that's a shame! Good to know not to spend time barking up that tree though, much appreciated.